# getting the dtype of the elements in np array

Tags: python, numpy

I am working to clear and manipulate csv data in numpy. i am getting this attribute error

load_metrics("covid_sentiment_metrics.csv") gives me a numpy array as an output which is passed to the next function as parameter

```
def unstructured_to_structured(data, indexes):
    '''structured to unstructured'''
    data_1 = np.delete(data, 0, 0)
    for i in range(np.shape(data_1)[1]):
        if i not in indexes:
            data_1[:, i] = (data_1[:, i]).astype(np.float64)
    data_1 = tuple([tuple(i) for i in data_1])
    return data_1

data = load_metrics("covid_sentiment_metrics.csv")
data = unstructured_to_structured(data, [0, 1, 7, 8])
print(data[5][0].dtype)

>>AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

the expected return should be float64 in this case.

Not sure what i doing wrong

** this is an addition to the previous post**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# this function returns a numpy array from a CSV file
def load_metrics(filename):
    '''read data as numpy array'''
    df = pd.read_csv('covid_sentiment_metrics.csv').astype(str)
    df.loc[-1] = df.columns.to_list()
    df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
    df.drop(columns=['text', 'screen_name', 'followers', 'friends', 'user_ID', 'country_region'], inplace=True)
    df_numpy = df.to_numpy()
    return df_numpy

# the return from above function is passed as parameters
def unstructured_to_structured(data, indexes):
    data_1 = np.delete(data, 0, 0)
    # I am trying to change the data type for those columns that are not listed in the indexes
    for i in range(np.shape(data_1)[1]):
        if i not in indexes:
            data_1[:, i] = (data_1[:, i]).astype(np.float64)
    data_1 = tuple([tuple(i) for i in data_1])
    return data_1


data = load_metrics("covid_sentiment_metrics.csv")
data = unstructured_to_structured(data, [0, 1, 7, 8])
print(data[5][0].dtype)

>>AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

i hope this should suffice for the situation to be clear

link to csv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3oq5zq71dd6sjx/covid_sentiment_metrics.csv?dl=0

Comment: You might want to use `type(data[5][0])` and not `dtype`. Please refer to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html to understand numpy.ndarray attributes, specifically - dtype.

Comment: the expected return should be float64 in this case.

Comment: Examine `data` at this line.  I'm guessing is a tuple of tuples.  I don't know what those inner tuples contain.  To debug code like this you need a lot of diagnostic prints.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by at least providing some information about the csv file or the numpy array it is generating.

Comment: Only numpy arrays have a dtype. Individual elements do not. Unless `data[5][0]` contains a numpy array (or a compatible type, like Pandas series), you will not find success.

Comment: Without your data, your csv we can't recreate the problem.  And running your code abstractly in our heads is too much work!.  Do your own debugging!

Comment: i have added the link to csv

Comment: That link is a lazy persons approach to providing the data.  I glanced at it, but am not interested in downloading it.  A link is not a [mcve].  I expect that dataframe created from this is object dtype in all columns, since the data is all strings.  If you are trying to change dtype of columns, why aren't you working with the dataframe itself.  The array derived from it will be object dtype.  Elements will have a type, but not a dtype.  `data1` starts as an array (from `delete` - why didn't you use slcing?).  Why convert to this tuple of tuples?